# can someone please explain this SQL code?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff, getdate, datecreated

```
WHERE(DATEDIFF(MONTH, datecreated, GETDATE()) = +1)
```

What should this do?

Comment: if the datedifference in months = 1

Comment: the +1 resolves to 1, so it's saying WHERE (expression) = 1. Expanded: where (datecreated month - current month) = 1, then true, else false.

Comment: This expression is not sargble. It won't be able to use an index seek on `datecreated`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is getting everything in the previous calendar month.  Note that this is specifically the previous calendar month, regardless of the current date.

Why is this the case?  `datediff()` counts the number of *boundaries* between two date/time values.  In this case, the boundary is the beginning/end of a month.  So, if today is 2017-05-05, then anything in 2017-04 has a single boundary.  Nothing in March does, nothing in May does.  Note that this is as true on May 1st as on May 31st.

Although this is handy, I think the code should at least have a comment, because it might not be obvious to a casual reader what is happening.